# NSURLSession treats http url as https, only on some devices

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have an app running on a test server that doesn't support https. I added the ATS exceptions in the info.plist and it worked well on the devices I tested on.

Now some of my test flight users started complaining about the app not being able to connect to the server. One of the devices in my office started having this problem too, so I had the change to look into it.

I am making a server request like this:

```
let path = "http://myurl.com"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
    print(NSString.init(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
})
task.resume()
```

Now when I look at the URL from the NSHTTPURLResponse it is printed as "https://myurl.com". Somehow it just added the 's' to it. This only happens on some devices, I can't seem to find a pattern.

When I open the https url in a browser I get redirected to some other project we're working on. When I look at the response data that's exactly what I see. So somehow on some devices when you enter a http url it just converts it to https or something...

So far it's only been on iOS9 devices, but that may very well be a coincidence. Does anyone have an idea why this happens and what to do about it?

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your web server configuration. The client is being redirected in some cases.

Comment: Yeah I wondered that myself too. If I could only figure out what 'some cases' is :(. Now that I think of it, I believe other apps from that server have been having similar issues. I'll talk to the server guy tomorrow, maybe he has an idea...

Comment: I would suggest enabling HTTPS support on the server.  HTTPS certs are free these days, and all modern servers and clients support SNI, so there's really no good reason to add ATS exceptions unless you're dealing with an ad network or arbitrary web content on servers that are out of your control.

Comment: The server guy enabled https support for the server and it is working well now. I had to make a new version of the app though because the POST requests didn't work anymore as the request address wasn't https.

Still strange that it's causing trouble on some devices and not on others.